# How can I pass a variable from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I have this code snippet:

```
function pWordValidate() {
    var pWord = document.getElementById("password");
    if (pWord.value.length < 6 || pWord.value.length > 20) {
        errorList("password must be between 6 - 20 length");
    }
    pWordValidate2(pWord);
}

function pWordValidate2(pWord) {
    var pWord2 = document.getElementById("retypepassword");
    if (pWord2 != pWord) {
        errorList("passwords do not match");
    }
    showErrors();
}
```

When I try to output "pWord" just above the line calling the 2nd function I get an output of "objectHTMLInputElement"

Comment: You need to compare the values not the elements. pWord2.value !== pWord.value etc.

Comment: ohh I see what you mean. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (pWord2 != pWord) {
```

should really be

```
if (pWord2.value != pWord.value) {
```

in fact both `pWord` and `pWord2` are DOM objects for which you need to compare the value.

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :)